# Firebase Realtime Database Billing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know if my unused firebase database GB transferred can be used in the next month or it becomes waste. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no rollover credits with Firebase billing.  Contact [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly for future questions about billing.

Comment: So my unused GB will be lost?

Comment: You retain nothing at the end of each billing cycle.  Contact support with further questions.